# Python Pandas , fixing values in a column and resetting the dtypes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My code reads a csv file into a pandas dataframe. 
However in cases where the csv file has 'null' values in columns I run into issues with the below error :
Columns (10,11,12) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
This null value is mostly found in the last row of the data.

I replace the null with np.nan as below :
df.replace('null', np.nan,inplace=True)

However the columns dtype still remains as an object. Is there a way to auto-reinitialize the dtypes or is there an optimal way to cleanup such data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameter `na_values` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, keep_default_na=False, na_values=["null"])
```

More information in pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-navaluesconst).

---

If all columns are `float`s is possible replace and cast:

```
df = df.replace('null', np.nan).astype(float)
```

You get `object dtype` after `replace`, because mixed values - `float`s (`NaN`s) with `string`s (numbers saved as `string`s).

Comment: Perfect ! I needed :df = pd.read_csv(path, keep_default_na=True, na_values=["null"])